# by using scanf stopped working

Tags: c

here is my code a part of a project when i initialize CHAR_1,CHAR_2 it works but when i read them by scanf it stopped working.

```c
int repair_beta(char beta[11][11])
{
    int i = 0, j = 0;
    int count = 0, n = 0;
    int fail = 0;
    for(i = 1; i < 11; i++)
    {
        for(j = 1; j < 11; j++)
        {
            if(beta[i][j] == stronghold)
            {
                count++;
            }
        }
    }
    if(count == 4)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    else if(count < 4)
    {
        char CHAR_1 = 'A', CHAR_2 = '5';
        for(n = 0; n < 3; n++)
        {
            printf("\n\t\t    <<choose to repair>>\n\t\t\t   ");
            scanf("%c", &CHAR_1);
            scanf("\n%c", &CHAR_2);
            for(i = 1; i < 11; i ++)
            {
                if(CHAR_1 == 'A' + i - 1)
                {
                    break;
                }
            }
            for(j = 1; j < 11; j++)
            {
                if(CHAR_2 == '0' + j - 1)
                {
                    break;
                }
            }
            if(beta[i][j] == LAND || beta[i][j] == land)
            {
                beta[i][j] = stronghold;
                prize_beta--;
                printf("\n\t\t\t <<repaired>>");
                printf("\n****************************************************************************\n");
                return 1;
            }
            else
            {
                fail++;
            }
        }
        if(fail == 3)
        {
            printf("\n\t\t      <<you failed to repair>>");
            prize_beta;
            printf("\n****************************************************************************\n");
        }
    }
}
```

it is my firs time i use stackoverflow so excuse me if i ask my question in bad way.

Comment: `scanf("\n%c", &CHAR_2);` ----> `scanf(" %c", &CHAR_2);`

Comment: @LPs I thought it shouldn't matter what whitespace character is used?

Comment: ... and the first one too `scanf("%c", &CHAR_1);` ==> `scanf(" %c", &CHAR_1);` because these two lines are in a loop.

Comment: @Siguza From [the man](https://linux.die.net/man/3/scanf): _To skip white space first, use an explicit space in the format_

Comment: it is working now thank a lot guys.

Comment: @LPs: all whitespace **is** the same: "A sequence of white-space characters (space, tab, newline etc.).  This directive matches any amount of white space, including none, in the input." (From the man page you linked)

Comment: @rici so why _explicit space_ is written? Wouldn't be _whitespace_ so? I learn something today: it's a good day ;)

Comment: @LPs If in doubt, consult the C standard ([link](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf)). Page 317, §5: _A directive composed of white-space character(s) is executed by reading input up to the first non-white-space character (which remains unread), or until no more characters can be read._

Comment: @Siguza There is clear: it is _white-space_ I was misled by _explicit_ in the man, and probably by my bad english ;)

Comment: @LPs: "explicit whitespace" might have been better, but the sentence you quote is advice. It is not a specification. The specification is the sentence above which I quoted. It is *best practice* to use a single space in a scanf format, because it is clear. But any whitespace character or characters *will work*.